# Thread.sleep pausing whole program

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep

I have a main form with a button, that when pressed, should start a new count-down timer thread.

This is the code in the button's action listener:

```
 Counter c = new Counter(timeToFinish);
```

This is the code for the Counter class:

```
class Counter implements Runnable {

        int waitingTime = 0;
        Thread myCounter = new Thread(this);

        public Counter(int waitingTime)
        {
            this.waitingTime = waitingTime;
            myCounter.run();
        }

        public void run(){

            //Start countdown:
            do  
            {

                waitingTime -= 1;

                try {

                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println(waitingTime);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } while (waitingTime >= 0);

        }
    }
```

The problem is, when I create a new instance of the Counter class, it pauses the whole program, not just that thread! The problem must be with "Thread.sleep".

Comment: why does the program pause? is it because the current thread is a UI thread? normally the main thread should run by pausing 1 sec for each counter right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are directly calling the **run** method.

Instead you should wrap it in a Thread and start the thread.

For e.g., replace

```
myCounter.run();
```

by

```
new Thread(this).start();
```

Answer (score 3):

Just because you call the `run` method from the `Counter` constructor. That's not how it works  with threads. You'll have to remove this call, wrap the `Runnable` in a `Thread` instance and call `start()` on  the thread:

```
 new Thread(new Counter(2)).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually `start()`ing multiple threads.

The `Thread.run()` method simply runs the code associated with the thread, like any other normal function.  It doesn't start a separate thread.

You need to call `Thread.start()`, to start a new thread and run your code in it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `start()` method of your thread. Use

```
c.start();
```

otherwise you have a class and you are invoking one of its methods, and of course it is running in main thread and sleeping the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling run directly, it'll run in the current thread, and sleep the current thread, which I guess is the event thread. This cause the pause in your program.

Answer (score -1):

You should use SwingUtilities class

see

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Threads/InvokeExampleSwingandthread.htm

```
    // Report the result using invokeLater().
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        resultLabel.setText("Ready");
        setEnabled(true);
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Swing was not even mentioned.

Comment: He mentioned a form with a button, which might indicate this is a GUI program.